# writing Rtf formatted text in word file using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, interop, rtf

i want to write rtf formatted text to word file from database by visual studio?
i am using BLOB for storing rtf data in database, in which rtf data is stored in encoded form.
i have already stored rtf data in database in encoded form taken from richtextbox, and now while writing into word file it is not converting into actual format of string.
but i have to write actual rtf string (not encoded string) in word file,
i tried but it will print encoded rtf string in word file.
how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7529/Saving-Rich-Edit-Control-Text-to-SQL-Server.htm

may be this can help you to retreive data from rtf textbox i have tried it and it worked for me